# Finding words in multiple text files

Tags: shell, loops, unix

Okay, so my homework problem needs me to create two separate scripts. I wrote out the first script, which will randomly assign one file with the text of "Found it!" while the others will have "Not here!". I successfully created the first script, however, I'm beyond stuck on my second script. What I need to write is a program that will find the random "Found it!" file between the multiple txt files. It needs to be run in a loop until it finds the one file. The catch is, I can not use "grep" or other utility..... Please help!

Below is the first successful script.

Any idea what to do for the second script?

```
!/bin/bash

random_num=$((RANDOM % 10))
egg_num=10

echo "$random_num"

while [ $egg_num -gt -1 ]

do
    if [ $egg_num == $random_num ]

    then

        echo "Found it!" > egg$egg_num.txt

        egg_num=$(($egg_num-1))

    else

        echo "Not here!" > egg$egg_num.txt

        egg_num=$(($egg_num-1))

fi
done
```

Comment: Presumably, one way to handle it is to capture the content of the file with `content=$(cat egg$egg_num.txt)` and then compare `"$content"` with `'Found it!'`, looking for equality.  Command substitution deletes trailing newlines.  Or, more generally, `for file in "$@"; do content="$(cat "$file")"; if [ "$content" = 'Found it!' ]; then echo "$file: $content"; fi; done` and pass a list of files to be processed.  This gets messy if any of the files is actually gigabytes instead of bytes.  (I think the condition placed on you is fairly pointless.)

Comment: When using `test` (equivalent to `[ ... ]`, the condition for string-equality is a single `'='` not `"=="`. Additionally, ALWAYS double quote your variables within it or risk error if the variable contains whitespace (`"too many arguments..."`). Instead of `cat` you can also use simple redirection, e.g. `content="$(< "$file")"`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for file in egg*                                                                                                                                            
do                                                                                                                                                            
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then                                                                                                                                        
    line=$(cat $file)                                                                                                                                           
    if [ "$line" = "Found it!" ]; then                                                                                                                             
       echo $file
       break                                                                                                                                                
    fi                                                                                                                                                       
  fi                                                                                                                                                            
done
```

Comment: `line=$(< $file)` - just an alternative. Additionally, "Try" and avoid prefacing answers with `"Try"`. It implies you are unsure about your answer and the OP should just "try it" and see if it works. A bit more explanation beyond `"Try"` is also welcomed by someone struggling to learn a particular concept. Like why is `$file` unqoted in `line=$(cat $file)`. What happens if it is quoted? What's the difference, etc.. What about `echo $file`? Does quoting matter there? Why? You get the picture.